# How to extract all numbers from string using find() method?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with numbers but not only numbers (in fact any alphanumeric character could be there) and I have to extract each valid positive integer from this string and add it to list.

I've tried using find() method and pattern "\d+" but there is problem when input string begins with integer. That integer at the very begining of the input string isn't extracted.

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

Matcher test = reg.matcher( "988 5454 754");

boolean matches = test.matches();

List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

while (test.find()) {
            numbers.add(test.group(0));
}
```

I expect group 0 in the first iteration contains 988, in the second 5454 and in the third 754 but it's not able to extract number 988 when string begins with integer.

I'm extracting only numbers 5454 and 754.

Is any error with my regex pattern?

EDIT:
I've completed the code. And you can see that invocation of the matches() method was causing the problem here.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? I see no reason why your code as it stands there won't print all 3 matches.

Comment: I just ran your code and printed the `number` array and it contains all 3 numbers: `988 5454 754`.  Can you post an example where your error is reproduced?

Answer (score 2):

Copy pasted your code and just added a sysout. It is printing 3 numbers. Possibly while reading the numbers you might have missed the first one. Check how you iterating through the list.

```
    Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

    Matcher test = reg.matcher( "988 5454 754");

    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (test.find()) {
                numbers.add(test.group(0));
    }

    Iterator<String> it = numbers.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

Output : 988
5454
754

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use find but it does offer alternatives. Pulls integers out of the string and places them in a list or array.  Requires Java 8+

```java
      String str = "ksks9292ksks02020ksks,x,slsk20209229,ss0202kslsks";
```

Leave as strings and place in a `List`.

```java
      List<String> numbStrList =
            Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+")).filter(a -> !a.equals("")).collect(
                  Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(numbStrList);
```

Leave as strings and place in an `array`

```java
      String[] numbStrArray =
            Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+")).filter(a -> !a.equals("")).toArray(
                  String[]::new);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbStrArray));
```

Convert to integers and place in a `List`

```java
      List<Integer> numbList =
            Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+")).filter(a -> !a.equals("")).map(
                  Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(numbList);
```

Convert to integers and place in an `array of int`

```java
      int[] numbArray =
            Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+")).filter(a -> !a.equals("")).map(
                  Integer::valueOf).mapToInt(a -> a).toArray();

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbArray));
```

The output is

```
[9292, 02020, 20209229, 0202]
[9292, 02020, 20209229, 0202]
[9292, 2020, 20209229, 202]
[9292, 2020, 20209229, 202]
```

Note for the conversion case, the leading zeroes are removed.

```java
Here are the salient parts of how it works.

      List<Integer> numbList =
            // create a stream of the array from split.  The split
            // splits on anything that does not constitute an integer
            Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))

            // remove any empty strings (can result when the string
            // starts with a non-integer).            
            .filter(a -> !a.equals(""))

            //convert to the actual value
            .map(Integer::valueOf)

             // collect them in a list.
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```